# Modal Window not detect well I click on the Login or Sign up button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When clicked close button code detects in the console that the component want's to be hidden but when I want to open the modal window by clicking the `Logic` or `Signup` button in `navigation.js` file those buttons don't detect any activity to the console.

This where I'm got the tutorial on how to do the modal widow but tried to work out for my need's --> https://alligator.io/react/modal-component/

**Modal Window Component:**

```
import React from 'react';

const Modal = ({ show, children }) => {
  const showHideClassName = show ? 'modal display-block' : 'modal display-none';

  return (
    <div className={showHideClassName}>
      <section className='modal-main'>
        {children}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};



class App extends React.Component {
    state = { show: false }

    showSignup = () => {
        this.setState({ show: true });
        console.log('I was triggered during componentDidMount')
    } 

    showLogin = () => {
        this.setState({ show: true });
        console.log('Fuck this not show the login form')
    }

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({ show: false });
        console.log('Yeah its hide the login and signup form')
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Modal show={this.state.show} handleclose={this.hideModal} >
                <div className="blkOverlay">
                    {/* This is Login Form to log in to your profile */ }
                    <div className="formContent modal-main">
                        <button className="closebtn" onClick={this.hideModal}>Close </button>
                        <h2>Welcome Back <span>Brandon!</span></h2>
                        <form data-show={this.state.show.toString()}>                         
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                            <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
                            <div className="passContent">
                                <div className="checkingPass">
                                    <input className="inline" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Remember Password"/>
                                    <span className="inline">Remember Password</span>
                                </div>
                                <p className="passFont">Forgot Password</p>
                            </div>

                            <input className="formmbtn" type="button" name="button" value="Login"/>
                            <div className="social-media-button">
                                <input className="clearbtn" type="button" name="button" value="Sign in with Facebook"/>
                                <div className="divider"/>
                                <input className="clearbtn" type="button" name="button" value="Sign in with Facebook"/>
                            </div>

                            <p className="passFont">Don't have an account? <span>Sign up</span></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    {/* This is Sign up to create a account */}

                </div>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Navigation Component (Where the buttons are at to call the modal window to appear on click)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dropdown from "../components//pages/dropdowns/dropdowns.js";
import "../components/pages/SignupModal/signupmodal.js";
import hamburger from "../images/menu.svg";

class Navigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isExpanded: false
        };
    }

    handleToggle(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          isExpanded: !prevState.isExpanded, // negate the previous expanded state
        }));
      }

    render() {

        const { isExpanded } = this.state;

      return (
          <Router>
              <div className="NavbarContainer">
                  <div className="mobilecontainer LeftNav">
                      <h2 className="BrandName LeftNav mobileboxmenu inline FarRight">Kommonplaces</h2>
                      <div className="hamburger inlinev" >
                          <img 
                            onClick={e => this.handleToggle(e)}
                            alt="menubtn" 
                            src={hamburger}
                          />
                      </div>
                  </div>


                  <ul className={`NavBar collapsed ${isExpanded ? "is-expanded" : ""}`}>
                        <Dropdown/>    
                        <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Host Your Space</Link></li>
                        <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">About Us</Link></li>
                        <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Contact Us</Link></li>
                        <div className="btnflexright">
                            <button className="RightNav"><Link onClick={ this.showSignup } to="/">Sign Up</Link></button>
                            <button className="RightNav"><Link onClick={ this.showLogin } to="/">Login</Link></button>
                        </div>
                  </ul>
               </div>
         </Router>
      );
    }
}

  export default Navigation;
```

Any, helpful tips and advice would help, please.

Comment: `showSignup` and `showLogin` are defined in `App.js`, yet you try to access them in the `Navigation` component. Why?

Comment: because I'm using this in my own project that why

Answer (score 0):

That's because you placed the onClick event in the Link rather than on the button component. Change to the code below:

```
<div className="btnflexright">
   <button className="RightNav" onClick={ this.showSignup }>
      <Link to="/">Sign Up</Link>
   </button>
   <button className="RightNav" onClick={ this.showLogin }>
      <Link to="/">Login</Link>
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have that the first time didn't do anything not show the Modal window when you click on the buttons

Comment: The link which happens to be an anchor tag seems to be interferring with the button's click event handler. Try to remove Link like below, and see if that works:

```<button className="RightNav" onClick={ this.showLogin }>
      Login
   </button>```

Comment: So, I clear cache but and remove the Link from the button tags did not work

Comment: I have taken time to look at your code, and your approach is wrong. You are calling `this.showSignup` but I can't find any function called `showSignup()` in the Navigation component. You probably want to examine that.

Comment: So, thinking the problem is that tried to import  `import "../components/pages/SignupModal/signupmodal.js";` but not recognizing the `showSignup()` so want to know how can call something that in a different file.